# What is the write SPI command for MX25R device

Tags: embedded, spi

I want to Write data to this device and read from it.using the manual shown below.

For writing At first I though I should do those two commands:

- 1st command `{0x06};//write enable command`
- 2nd command `{0x01,0x2F,0xEF,0xD8}; //write status register based on the table below`

But then I saw The PP command which from Fig. 30 shown below which starts with 0x02.

So I assume that in order to store data on this device I need to add 0x02 to my sequence as following send MSB first )

- 1st command `{0x06};//write enable command`
- 2nd command `{0x02,0x01,0x2F,0xEF,0xD8} // PP sequence and Write STATUS register the data 0x2F,0xEF,0xD8`.

Have I assembled the sequence correctly for this command?

Thanks.

https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7461/MX25R8035F,%20Wide%20Range,%208Mb,%20v1.6.pdf

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is possibly an X-Y problem - what is it you are trying to do?  WRSR is not a means of programming the flash memory.  It is not clear why you are conflating WRSR and PP.  I think you really need to read and understand the data sheet more thoroughly and not by randomly picking out sections.  This is perhaps not the site for that as it is not a coding issue.   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ perhaps, but take care that your question is not of the "_read the datasheet for me_" kind.  That is read it first and ask _specific_ questions about parts you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page programming (PP command 0x02) is not the same as Write Status Register (WRSR command 0x01), so no clearly you don't prepend the sequence with 0x02, since it will then be a PP command and will write data to the device's flash memory, rather the the status register.

WRSR timing diagram is Fig. 15 of the data sheet you linked.  PP has no relevance here if WRSR is what you want to do.  Conversely if you want to program the flash memory, that is not what WRSR does.

The device has registers for controlling its operation and checking its status, and it has flash memory for storing data - and different commands for accessing these.

Your sequence: `0x02,0x01,0x2F,0xEF,0xD8` will write a single byte 0xD8 to address 0x012FEF.  The data sheet says that the LSB of the address should be zero, but does explain what happens when that is not the case, so it is well defined if ill-advised and unlikly to be what you intended. But thereagain it seems likley that writing `0x2FEFD8` to the Status Register was also not what you intended.

The datasheet does have some language issues to hinder you perhaps.  For example the PP section uses the word "effort" where I think it intended "effect".

Comment: Hello Clifford,So  if understand  correctly for example i want to write to adress all zeros the value of 1111 1111 which is FF in hex so the correct command is

0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,FF

So first the {0x06};//write enable command in the start?

then the PP command 0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,FF

If i want to read from that adress the value FF then i should do by fig18 to do

0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00

correct?
https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7461/MX25R8035F,%20Wide%20Range,%208Mb,%20v1.6.pdf